# Why are tuples enclosed in parentheses?

Tags: python

> a tuple is a comma-separated list of values

so the valid syntax to declare a tuple is:

```
tup = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
```

But what I often see is a declaration like this:

```
tup = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

What is the benefit of enclosing tuples in parentheses ?

Comment: readability, for starters.

Comment: Somebody famous once said "*Sometimes a parenthesis is just a parenthesis.*" The comma makes the tuple, the parentheses just do what they always do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parentheses are just parentheses - they work by changing precedence. The only exception is if nothing is enclosed (ie `()`) in which case it will generate an empty tuple.

The reason one would use parentheses nevertheless is that it will result in a fairly consistent notation. You can write the empty tuple and any other tuple that way.

Another reason is that one normally want a literal to have higher precedence than other operations. For example adding two tuples would be written `(1,2)+(3,4)` (if you omit the parentheses here you get `1,2+3,4` which means to add 2 and 3 first then form the tuple - the result is `1,5,4`). Similar situations is when you want to pass a tuple to a function `f(1,2)` means to send the arguments 1 and 2 while `f((1,2))` means to send the tuple `(1,2)`. Yet another is if you want to include a tuple inside a tuple `((1,2),(3,4)` and `(1,2,3,4)` are two different things.

Answer (score 10):

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> ... so that nested tuples are interpreted correctly. Tuples may be
>   input with or without surrounding parentheses, although often
>   parentheses are necessary anyway (if the tuple is part of a larger
>   expression).

Example of nested tuples:

```
tuple = ('a', ('b', 'c'), 'd')
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are good answers! Here's just an additional example of tuples in action (packing/unpacking):

If you do this

```
x, y = y, x
```

what's happening is:

```
tuple_1 = (y, x)
(x, y) = tuple_1
```

which is the same as:

```
tuple_1 = (y, x)
x = tuple_1[0]
y = tuple_1[1]
```

In all *these cases* the parenthesis *don't do anything at all to the python*. But they are helpful if you want to say to someone reading the script "*hey! I am making a tuple here! If you didn't see the comma I'll add these parenthesis to catch your eye!*"

Of course the answers about nested tuples are correct. If you want to put a tuple inside something like a tuple or list...

```
A = x, (x, y)   # same as (x, (x, y))
B = [x, (x, y)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the editing but I've rolled it back.It is ok and not unusual to call python script just "python", and many would argue that the term "script" is better than "code" when applied to python. And I think I have seen many examples of high reputation contributors adding a few words of credit to other answers before adding their contribution as an additional answer. When there are many answers, these cues can help guide a reader coming to the question. They have certainly helped me.